# how to store string value in array of string to Print all value in single line

Tags: java, android

```
for(int i=0; i<jArray.length(); i++) {
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

    name = json_data.getString("name");
    map.put("id",  String.valueOf(json_data.getString("news_id")));

    map.put("title",json_data.getString("news_title"));
    map.put("shortdescription",json_data.getString("news_short_description"));
    mylist.add(map);
}
```

This my data and i m able to Print data in Listview lv.setAd..(mylist)

But i have to collect all news_title in string array so that i can display news title under so that i can display all data in single line with morqee .

please help me how to store data in string aray . i m new in android

Comment: map.put("title",json_data.getString("news_title"));
 whole news_title i want to store in single string so that i can print data in single line ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not really following your question. A String is an array of chars so umm? That being said, what is the issue exactly do mean you are having trouble with Json or do want to accumlate data into a single string. Not sure exactly what is the problem here. So have 2 seperate ideas based on my limited understanding.

A) Json issue : Getting a string into Json format in Java looks like this:

JsonObject temp = new JsonObject();
   temp.addProperty(myString);

then when done adding to the output create your output string

```
String outputString = mySon.toJson(temp);
```

b) If you want to know how to accumlate data into a single string this is also easy

myString = myString + " " + newStringData;

but in the json model just keep using

```
temp.addProperty(myString); //for each item you want to add
```

Comment: actually i  am  getting  news title under for loop different title for different id but i want store the whole id title in single string so that i can print all string in single text view with morquee style.

Comment: Still lost, i don't get what you want to do. Seems like you want to print out all the titles in the list in a single string if that is the case then: myString = myString + " " + map.get("news_title"); should work and you dont even need the Array list at all (at least not for this task).

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the list of maps, then fetch the values for the `title` keys and store them in a temporary list. Finally ask the list to adapt itself to an array (last line).

```
List<String> titlesList = new ArrayList<String>();
for (Map<String, String> map : myList) {
   titlesList.add(map.get("title"));
}
String[] titles = titlesList.toArray(new String[]{});
```

Comment: actually i am getting news title under for loop different title for different id but i want store the whole id title in single string so that i can print all string in single text view with morquee style.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your requirement. My four lines of code (to be added after your for-loop) will create a string array where each array item is one news title.

Comment: when i debug for (Map<String, String> map1 : mylist) it doesnt go to inside  for loop titlesList.add(map.get("news_title"));
so i m not getting value

Comment: Sorry, my bad, the key in your map is "title" - I've corrected my example. Sorry for that confusion :) NOW it should work.

Comment: myString = myString + " " + json_data.getString("news_title").toString();    its working Properly now